# Adding properties to camel context in Java

Tags: java, properties, apache-camel, deprecated

While going through an existing camel project, I came across a statement like this in `MyClass extends RouteBuilder`.

```
getContext().getProperties().put("CamelJacksonEnableTypeConverter", "true");
```

But, in this scenario, `getProperties` method is marked as deprecated. So, what should be the current approach for setting properties in camel context?

Comment: See the javadoc of that method, it ought to have a reference to what to use - http://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.19.3

Comment: @ClausIbsen. Okay it helps. Actually, I was referring to an older version of documentation in which it was not deprecated. My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the the [Java Document for `CamelContext` class](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.19.3), we can see the following

> **getProperties**
>
> @Deprecated
>
> Map getProperties()
>
> **Deprecated**. use getGlobalOptions() instead.

It clear states, we need to use `getGlobalOptions` instead of using `getProperties`.